# Finding the index of second smallest number in the list?

Tags: ruby

How can I find the second smallest number and return its index?

Comment: Hint: what if the list was sorted?

Comment: no i don't want to sort because i need to return the index of the number

Comment: Once you find the value, you can find the index, right? That will give you an O(nlogn) solution. There is also a O(n) solution that doesn't involve sorting - basically you track the two smallest numbers `min` and `min2` as you iterate through the unsorted array.

Comment: what is the code that make me find the number without sort and the return its index

Comment: What have you tried? And why don't you want to use `sort`? Is this homework?

Comment: It looks like homework

Answer (score 3):

Another approach :

```
>> a = [1,3,5,6,2,4]
=> [1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4]
>> a.index(a.sort[1])
=> 4
>>
```

Comment: OP specified he didn't want to use `sort`.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the description itself. :(

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options from the top of my head:

Delete the current min, so the new min will be the previous second min

```
arr = num.delete(num.min)
min_bis = arr.min
```

Loop through the array, using 2 variables to store the 2 lowest values.
This might be a little trickier but the complexity would only be O(n).

I don't know why you don't want to sort the array, but if it's a performance issue, it's probably one of the best options (to sort it) especially if the array is small.

Answer (score 0):

(Below, `Enumerable` is a superset of `Array`, `Hash` and `Range` etc.)

`Enumerable#sort` returns a fresh array containing all the elements of the original object in a sorted order, so you can write `a = num.sort[1]` (provided that `l > 1`) to find the second smallest number, *without* modfying the original input `nums`.

Then you can feed it to `Enumerable#find_index`.

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index

By the way

```
while (index <l)
  nums - gets.to_i
  num[index] = nums
  index +=1
end
```

can be written as

```
nums = (0...l).map{ gets.to_i }
```

Comment: Don't write `(0...l)`. That's equivalent to `(0..0)`.

Comment: I dont want to sort the array I want to find the element without sorting

Comment: @theTinMan it's `l` (small el,) not `1` (digit one.) `l = 3; (0...3).to_a => [0, 1, 2]`

Comment: @theTinMan my bad, i meant `l = 3; (0...l).to_a => [0, 1, 2]`

Comment: And that's why we don't use lower-case "L" for variable names, nor capital-"oh" ("O")

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that does not use `sort`:

```
arr = [3,1,2,5,1]
```

If `second_smallest(arr) => 2` is desired:

```
def second_smallest(arr)
  return nil if arr.uniq.size < 2 
  mn, mx = arr.min, arr.max
  arr.map! { |e| e == mn ? mx : e }
  arr.index(arr.min) 
end
```

If `second_smallest(arr) => 4` is desired:

```
def second_smallest(arr)
  return nil if arr.uniq.size < 2
  i1 = arr.index(arr.min)
  arr.delete_at(i1)
  i2 = arr.index(arr.min)
  i2 >= i1 ? i2 + 1 : i2 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't want to sort the array before finding the second-lowest number. But are you willing to use a sorted clone/copy of that array?

If

```
nums = [1, 5, 1, 9, 3, 8]
```

Then:

```
# grab a sorted copy of nums
b = nums.sort

# b = [1, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]
# delete the lowest number
b.delete(b.min)

# now b = [3, 5, 8, 9]
# so get the index from the original array
nums.index(b.first)
```

which should return `4` because `nums[4] = 3`. (You could also use `nums.index(b[0])` since b is already sorted.)

Comment: I need it without sorting the array

Comment: Asker, C sorts a copy, gets the second-smallest, then finds the index of that value in the original array. I may have mislead you in an erroneous comment that I posted then deleted.

Comment: Without sorting `nums`, or without sorting anything?

Comment: You might replace `b.min` with `b.first` in your last statement.

Comment: Good point. I had `.min` and `[0]` in my head so much that I forgot about `.first`. Thanks.

Comment: @CFishburn You don't need `clone`. `a=[1,3,2]; a.sort => [1,2,3]` but the original `a` remains unchanged; `a => [1,3,2]`.  Perhaps you had `Enumerable#sort!` (note the last `!`) in your mind.

Comment: No... I was doing something a bit more convoluted in irb, and `.clone` got stuck there. I've updated the code. Thanks @nodakai!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind being destructive to the original array:

```
a.delete(a.min)
a.index(a.min)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use sort as it's O(nlogn). You want to iterate through the array only once (after getting the max):

```
arr = [123,35,12,34,5,32]
```

This is a straight forward way of solving the problem:

```
def second_min_index(arr)
  max = arr.max
  min, min_index, second_min, second_min_index = max, 0, max, 0

  arr.each_with_index do |e, i| 
    # if something is less than min, second min should become what used to be min
    if (e <= min) 
      second_min, second_min_index, min, min_index = min, min_index, e, i 
    # if something is less than second min (but not less than min)
    # it becomes the second min
    elsif (e < second_min)
      second_min, second_min_index = e, i
    end
  end

  second_min_index
end

second_min_index(arr)
=> 2
```

A better and more reusable way of doing this would be via a transform and conquer solution (just in case you get asked for the 3rd smallest number):

```
def min_index(arr)
  min, min_index = arr[0], 0
  arr.each_with_index { |e,i| min, min_index = e,i if e < min }
  min_index
end

def min_index_excluding(arr, exclude_indexes)  
  min, min_index = arr[0], 0
  arr.each_with_index { |e,i| min, min_index = e,i if (e < min && !exclude_indexes.include?(i)) }
  min_index
end

def second_min_index(arr)
  min_index_excluding(arr, [min_index(arr)])
end

second_min_index(arr)
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_sorted = a.sort
second_min = a_sorted[1]
a.index(second_min)
```